# how to fetch data from mysql and write it to innerhtml of a div in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Apologies for the newbie question, I just started with PHP, trying to fetch data when the user writes ID, and get info from database and write it into innerhtml of div's inside the form. How can I do it? thanks.

```
<form action="read.php" method="post">
    Bring Data of ID <input type="text" name="id" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
    <br/>
    <div id="username" style="font-weight:bold;" /></div>
    <br/>
    <div id="email" style="font-weight:bold;" /></div>
    <br/>
    <div id="password" style="font-weight:bold;" /></div>
</form>
```

---

```
<?php

    $db_username = "root";
    $db_password = "";

    $con =  new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $db_username, $db_password);
    if (!$con) {
        echo "error";
    }
    else {
        echo "connected";
    }

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        $query = $con->prepare(" SELECT * FROM bucky (username, email, password) WHERE id=:id ");
        $query->execute(array(
            ':id' => $_POST['id']
        ));
    }
    else {
        die("Die hacker!");
    }
```

Comment: So the second codeblock fetches your data i assume? And the first one gathers the id information from the user right?
And now you want to present your user a html file with his/her user data? correct?

Comment: consider accepting my answer to prevent this question from getting more unneeded attention, or if my answer didn't solve your problem, use the comments section to ask for further detail.

Answer (score 0):

In your read.html, append your html code at the end:

```
<?php

    [...]

        $query = $con->prepare(" SELECT * FROM bucky (username, email, password) WHERE id=:id ");
        $query->execute(array(
            ':id' => $_POST['id']
        ));
        $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    }
    else {
        die("Die hacker!"); // seriously?
    }
    ?><html><body><?php 
      print_r($result); ?>
    </body></html>
```

This will print you the result of your query.
You can also iterate over the result, but i think you should really just read the documentation on PDO and how to use it. Maybe a simple introduction to PHP as well. This is a VERY basic Question.